# Write one of model's attributes to the database and then read entire model from this single attribute

Tags: python, pydantic

I am trying to create a `Currency` model that wraps `pycountry`'s `Currency` object. This model will include the currency code and full name. However, I only want to store the code in my database when I call the model's `.dict()` method. When this code is then read from the database, it should use `pycountry` to retrieve the full currency object and store the currency name in the model too.

```
import pycountry
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Currency(BaseModel):
    code: str
    name: str

    def __init__(self, code: str):
        currency = pycountry.currencies.get(alpha_3=code)
        super().__init__(code=currency.alpha_3, name=currency.name)

    def dict(self, **kwargs):
        return self.code


class Country(BaseModel):
    name: str
    currency: Currency


country = Country(name="United States of America", currency=Currency("USD"))
print(country)
```

This prints:

```
name='United States of America' currency=Currency(code='USD', name='US Dollar')
```

Now I use `country.dict()` to write to my MongoDB database.

This looks like:

```
name                       | currency
-------------------------------------
'United States of America' | 'USD'
```

Now when I read this from the database, I want the object to be the same as when I printed it before, with `currency` populated as `Currency(code='USD', name='US Dollar')`, but when I do read this `Country` from the database, I am getting `value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that the result you want ?

```py
import pycountry
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Currency(BaseModel):
    code: str
    name: str

    def __init__(self, code: str):
        currency = pycountry.currencies.get(alpha_3=code)
        super().__init__(code=currency.alpha_3, name=currency.name)


class Country(BaseModel):
    name: str
    currency: Currency


country = Country(name="United States of America", currency=Currency("USD"))
print(country)
print(country.dict())
```

```bash
name='United States of America' currency=Currency(code='USD', name='US Dollar')
{'name': 'United States of America', 'currency': {'code': 'USD', 'name': 'US Dollar'}}
```